# copying music, pictures and movies from a galaxy s 4g to the pc

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, file-management, media-files

My daughter would like to copy (not transfer) her songs, pictures and a movie she has on her Galaxy S 4 G cell phone over to our PC.  How can she do this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you mention which operating system your PC is running.

On Windows 7 and above, you simply need to connect the phone to your PC using a USB-MiniUSB cable. You should then be able to access the files on the phone via Windows Explorer. You can then use Windows Explorer to copy files to and from your PC.

On Windows XP and below, you will need to either:
a) download and install [Samsung KIES](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/)

b) download and install the [Samsung Mobile Device USB Drivers](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I545ZKAVZW)

Once the drivers/software are installed, follow the same steps as for a Windows 7+ PC.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the operating system, your daughter could simply use a remote management app like [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). The advantage is: This app is installed on the device, and on the "remote" (here: PC) no special software is required but a web browser. Connection is either done via a shared WiFi network (both devices on the same network), or via the Aridroid server (if there is no shared network, and you have no problems routing your data via alien servers).

Airdroid uses a nice interface, which gives you desktop feeling inside of your browser:

[image: AirDroid]
<sup>Airdroid (source: Google Play; click image for larger variant)</sup>

Not only can you simply drag-and-drop files to transfer, but you can also manage other aspects of your device: accessing its contacts, writing SMS, viewing pictures, and a lot of other things.

And when your daughter is visiting her girlfriend, and wants to share some files with her: No hazzle with drivers or thinking about what OS might be in use. Simply fire up Airdroid, enter the displayed URL in her girlfriend's browser, put the password in the browser, and there she goes.

"Unwanted access"? Sure, if she let's her device lying around unlocked, so someone could fire up Airdroid and make the connection. But honestly, without Airdroid in the same situation the same person simply needed a cable to connect, and could do the same. And as not letting the device lying around unlocked should be a common-sense pre-caution, all stays as safe as before :)